Data rolled back after 5-7 minutes of running the update on table successfully
I ran an update on the SQL table using the below code, and it updated the table correctly. But after 5-7 minutes, the data rolls back. Why does this happen? I don't see any logs or errors in the SQL Server Logs. Any recommendations?
update APP_RecipeIngredients 
set Ingredient = 'DIM', IngredientDesc = 'DIMODAN ML90'
where BOMCode in ('088100','088088')
  and Revision in (2,3)
  and Deleted = 'N'
  and Ingredient = '088471'

The data updates with the new ingredient DIM but it rolls back to 088471 again after few minutes.

Have you some transaction open?

Have you committed the operation after executing the update command?
It could happen 'Update' command expects 'commit;' if it is part of a transaction,
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
UPDATE your_table
SET column1 = value1
WHERE condition;
COMMIT;
Ensure proper Locks on 'your_table' is acquired to ensure 'update' command runs on it, if it is unable to acquire lock on that table then it is possible 'update' command could rollback.
